# When I pass a long variable into Thread.Sleep(), this doesn't work right

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, parseint

This works: `Thread.Sleep(1000)`

This does not work: `Thread.Sleep(frequency)`

The frequency variable takes `edittext` input from a user and parses it into an integer so it should pass just fine. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Help appreciated :)

```
private void FlashButtonClicked() {
        startPattern = true;
        try{
            frequency = Long.parseLong(frequencyInput.getText().toString());
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "value not acceptable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        frequency = (1 / frequency) * 1000;
        while(startPattern){
            enableTorch();
            try{
                // see if you can figure out why I can't pass the user input into the
                //Thread.sleep() method without it fucking up. When you change it manually with
                // a long input, it works just fine.
                Thread.sleep(frequency);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: I am trying to get the camera flash to blink at a regular frequency. When I manually type in the millisecond delay for Thread.Sleep(), it works. When I pass the variable, it doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doens't work"? What happens?

Comment: The camera flash does not activate at the correct frequency. It just blinks wildly. When I type in the number of milliseconds, it works just fine. Only issue is when I try to pass that variable from the user input EditText widget(Which i cast to a long).

Comment: You don't need to call `toString()` on a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

If frequency is of type `long` and is greater than 1, then `1/frequency` is zero (because `/` means integer division). Replace it with:  `frequency = 1000/frequency`

Comment: And to think it was that simple. Thank you sir! It's time to take a break tonight I believe.